# How to plot histogram against class label for TF.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, machine-learning, histogram

I'm loading data from the disk with [TF.CsvDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CsvDataset). And plotting the data as

```
#This is the transformation function applied on loaded data before displaying histogram.
def preprocess(*fields):
    print(len(fields))
    features=tf.stack(fields[:-1])
    labels=tf.stack([int(x) for x in fields[-1:]])
    return features,labels  # x, y

for features,label in train_ds.take(1000):
#  print(features[0])
plt.hist(features.numpy().flatten(), bins = 101)
```

And I'm getting this histogram

[image]

But I want to plot distribution of 712 features' values against binary class labels. That is, what is the value of feature 1,2 or 3 when class label is 0.

**How to do that with pyplot?**

I have read following threads but, nothing helped.

[Plotting histograms against classes in pandas / matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548750/plotting-histograms-against-classes-in-pandas-matplotlib)

[Histogram color by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250670/histogram-color-by-class)

[How to draw an histogram with multiple categories in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026904/how-to-draw-an-histogram-with-multiple-categories-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62436302/extract-target-from-tensorflow-prefetchdataset

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56226621/how-to-extract-data-labels-back-from-tensorflow-dataset

Comment: Hi @NicolasGervais Thanks for these links but I can get labels. I'm just asking to plot my data with class labels categorization.

Comment: I updated the question for clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.fromiter` and get all the labels. Then you simply pass the list of labels to `plt.hist`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train, test = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train)

vals = np.fromiter(ds.map(lambda x, y: y), float)

plt.hist(vals)
plt.xticks(range(10))
plt.title('Label Frequency')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'm sorry for inconvenience but I want distribution of data.. to be precise floating values of 712 features against two binary classes 0 and 1.

Comment: Or as per the discussion on this answer, I think I'm using the wrong graph.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/52060028/7344164

Comment: I think I want something like this https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/xcorr_acorr_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-xcorr-acorr-demo-py